# how to show a tabular result in JIRA

Tags: jira, jql

I can get a list of Jira tickets based on specific ticket type. Now what I am looking is to generate a report of those tickets which will be shown as table. Let say I have these tickets

```
TC-1: myurl/to/address1
TC-2: myurl/to/address2
TC-3: myurl/to/address1
TC-4: myurl/to/address3
```

I want to generate table from these tickets like this

```
----------------------------------
|Title               |    Count  |
----------------------------------
|myurl/to/address1   |    2      |
|myurl/to/address2   |    1      |
|myurl/to/address3   |    1      |
----------------------------------
```

how to generate above table from ticket results?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an Issue Statistics gadget in a dashboard. However, not all fields can be used to group results by, so you may have to export to Excel and do the report there